# Joining Two SQL Tables in a query

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have two tables (with the same schema)

```
Table1
id   title   D0    D1    D2    D3
------------------------------------
1    Title1  0.12  3.23  4.90 -0.12
1    Title1  0.22  0.32 -4.90  0.12
1    Title1  0.13  1.24  3.50 -0.22
...
1    TitleN  1.22  2.33  3.90 -1.56
```

and

```
Table2
id   title   D0    D1    D2    D3
------------------------------------
1    Title1  1.42 -0.93 -2.99  3.22
1    Title1  0.52  3.32 -4.90  0.54
1    Title1  2.13  1.14  3.50 -0.22
...
1    TitleN  3.42  4.37  3.90 -1.26
```

I am trying to figure out how to do a query like can do this math:

```
SELECT title FROM Table2 WHERE (Table1_Row1_D0*Table2_Row1_D0)+(Table1_Row1_D1*Table2_Row1_D1)+(Table1_Row1_D2*Table2_Row1_D2) < 0.5;
```

However, I would like the query to iterate through the rows of Table1 and perform the SELECT against the entire Table2. Basically, I want to select the titles from Table2 where the calculation inequality is met against ALL the row combination of Table1 and Table 2.

Is this possible???

Not sure it matters, but I am using Postgre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want a CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT Table2.title 
FROM Table2 
CROSS JOIN Table1
WHERE (Table1.D0*Table2.D0)+(Table1.D1*Table2.D1)+(Table1.D2*Table2.D2) < 0.5;
```

Comment: A really good question.  The standard use of CROSS JOIN is to produce a "Cartesian Product" -- that is, CROSSing an M-row table with an N-row table will give you M*N rows.  There is no JOIN condition on a CROSS JOIN.  The standard use of an INNER JOIN is to find matching records based on one or more matching columns in two tables.  Technically, you could write the CROSS JOIN as an INNER JOIN without matching columns, but you would just confuse people.

Comment: "where the calculation inequality is met against ALL the row combination of Table1 and Table 2" - this doesn't seem to be covered? Take just 2 rows in t1 and 1 in t2. Say row1 returns true and row2 returns false for the condition, this query STILL shows table2.title.... this answer can also show the duplicate table2.title many times..

Answer (score 2):

> Basically, I want to select the titles
>   from Table2 where the calculation
>   inequality is met against ALL the row
>   combination of Table1 and Table 2.

For that you will want the reverse condition, where there does NOT exist an equality in Table1 for that Table2 row.

```
SELECT distinct title
FROM Table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    WHERE (Table1.D0*Table2.D0)+(Table1.D1*Table2.D1)
            +(Table1.D2*Table2.D2) >= 0.5
)
```

Comment: Honestly, this answer is a more precise answer to the asker's question (except for what appears to be a syntax error).  On the other hand, my answer allows you to get the titles from both tables, and so is a little more flexible.

Comment: "Table1_Row1_D0":  Shouldn't there be dots in there instead of periods?  I have to admit that I don't know the postgresql dialect, so I may be mistaken.  However, their site uses dots:  http://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/books/aw_pgsql/node59.html

Comment: @anon - You're right. I worked from the last query in the question and thought those were the field names (the whole `table1_row1_d0` etc). Didn't even look twice.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a union.  The only caveat is your returning fields from your selects must match

```
 (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE conditions) UNION (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE conditions)
```

Do your checks on the script side as long as your not pulling up too much data.  You also have the option to add sub selects to the where condition to limit both sides of this union query.